# Measuring averages of a seperate layer with kernel Density overlay

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, kernel-density

How can I get an average of another layer in a kernel density plot? I have bathymetry underlying my kernel density plot and need to know how to gain an average of bathymetry for a 80% kernel. Does any one have any ideas?

I am using Arcmap 10.1

[image: Need an average of bathymerty beneath the Red (80%) and green (20%)]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Zonal Statistics (Spatial Analyst)](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//009z000000w7000000) or [Zonal Statistics as Table (Spatial Analyst)](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//009z000000w8000000) to accomplish your task.  Make sure the input zone data are classified into the value ranges of interest to you (e.g. 0-10, 10-20, 20-30...) or simply take a subset of your kernel density raster (e.g. all values = 80).